# Transparent modal view on top of another view

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to create a modal view using Xcode's storyboard. I want it to consist of a small opaque view within a transparent view, so as to look like what would be called a popup window in desktop terminology.

I've created a segue to the new view controller, set it to "Present Modally" and its presentation to "Current Context", created my opaque view in the new view controller, and then set the background of the view of the new view controller to "Clear Color", and unchecked "Opaque".

When I trigger the segue, the new box slides into place over the previous view, exactly as it should, but then as soon as the animation ends, the background goes black.

What's going wrong here? How can I make the background stay transparent and the old view remain visible?

Comment: Take a look at this [forum](http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=18661)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [category](https://github.com/evnaz/ENPopUp) and change the code for you have the transparent modal view. In file `UIViewController+ENPopUp.m` you just have add `[popUpView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];` in the end of `presentPopUpView` method.

I hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use View Controller Containment:
[iOS Developer Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH11-SW1)

```
// Sample code you can use in your UIViewController

func addChildVC(child: UIViewController) {
    self.addChildViewController(child)
    child.view.bounds = self.view.bounds
    self.view.addSubview(child.view)
    child.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
}

func removeChildVC(child:UIViewController) {
    child.willMoveToParentViewController(nil)
    child.view.removeFromSuperview()
    child.removeFromParentViewController()
}
```